# Where can i find more info about NoiseModel?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I'm working on some camera noises like distortion, aberration etc. I think that I can achieve this easy by modify output images. But this options may by slow.
I prefer to add some shaders that could do in during render. I found here some kind of idea:
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/611/modelling-of-sensor-noise/
There appear "Sensor noise model". In repository history appear commit that says It worked.
I would like to know something more about "Noise Model" feature.
Are there any information about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5592/where-can-i-find-more-info-about-noisemodel?/) by [Marcin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/655/marcin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

currently gazebo supports `gaussian` noise model, and for camera sensors that's done through shaders
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.6/sensor_noise

unfortunately we don't provide easy hooks to use your custom shaders yet, but if you don't mind a bit of a hack, you can modify gazebo's camera gaussian noise shaders to suit your needs:

The shaders are: `/usr/share/gazebo-x.x/media/materials/programs/camera_noise_gaussian_*.glsl`

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0